# How can I check if an XML response contains a pattern?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

My response is below.

```
<reply>
    <status description="Error: REST call to http://localhost:8090/nmradapter/nmr/getICCIDDetails/123 failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost:8090/nmradapter/nmr/getICCIDDetails/123 " />
</reply>
```

I have used XML parser to parse the response and with the response I need to check if the status description contains response code 503.

*EDIT*:

I just wonder if there is a way where we can match three words (say `HTTP`, `Response code`, `503`) using regex even if the words don't occur in the same order in the sentence.

Can someone suggest a regex using groovy to match this condition?

Comment: Look for `HTTP response code: 503`? I mean, how hard is that? The problem is that if the error message changes, you're doomed. Why aren't you just looking at the response code from the request?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. Whenever my adapter is down .i get this response. I make a rest call to my adapter. So i need a regex pattern to find if my error description  contains response code 503

Comment: I think you can research regex and figure out how to match a string. You don't even need a regex for such a trivial case. My point still stands: why are you interrogating response text when you can just query the response itself?

Comment: My response text will still contain description as "Error:Contact to downstream failed" when my adapter is up but my connection to the middleware fails . hence i need to find if my Error desc contains a response code 503 to tell my front end that the adapter is actually down and not the middleware.

Comment: String.contains is your friend here, not regex

Comment: @manojkumar You response object should contain a code field. No need to parse the actual payload.

Comment: As @MarkusWMahlberg mentioned, you should actually be using the response code field on your response, but just for reference, you can use a positive lookahead assertion regex for this sort of thing: `^(?=.*503)(?=.*response code)(?=.*http)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Groovy, you can use the following check (assuming `text` is the variable holding the string you provided in the question):

```
if (text=~/Server returned HTTP response code: 503\b/){ 
  println "503 code detected"
} else {
   println "503 code not detected"
}
```

But it also seems you can just use `contains`:

```
if (text.contains('HTTP response code: 503 ') {...}
```

Comment: Thanks stribizhev . I have used contains itself. I was just wondering if there is a way where we can match three words (say HTTP response code: 503) using regex even if it doesnt occur in the same pattern in the sentence. Like the regex pattern should only look for the three words such as "HTTP" ,"Response code", "503" ..

Comment: Yes, we can do that with regexes, and without them. A regex way: use alternatives e.g. `text=~/\b(?:HTTP|Response code|503)\b/` (or case-insensitive `text=~/(?i)\b(?:HTTP|Response code|503)\b/`). Non-regex: just use split by space and punctuation, and then check with `Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourValue)`... I prefer a regex way then, as the code is shorter and clearer (for me) as I prefer as minimum lines of code as possible. I know there are many more people who will say the opposite :).

Comment: Hi. Thanks much. That works . The above expression will match when either one of those three words occurs in the string. What if i want to match only if all the three words are three. Is there any regex i can use a '&' operator instead of '|' symbol.

Comment: You can, but you will have to account for all cases of word order which is not cool. `\bHTTP\b.*\bResponse code\b.*\b503\b|\bHTTP\b.*\b503\b.*\bResponse code\b...`